# 2 sites availables for one website since SSL installed in /etc/apache2/sites-available

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, symfony-2.3, lets-encrypt

I have installed lets encrypt for my website :

I had previously mysite.com.conf in sites-available 
and now that it's installed 
there is also mysite.com-le-ssl.conf

Both are enabled; shall I disabled mysite.com.conf?
Or shall I keep both enabled.

In the CMS I use, they suggest to modify the configuration of apache and I don't know if I should edit mysite.com.conf or mysite.com.le-ssl.conf or both...

please help

Thank you

Comment: Well do you still want your site to be reachable via HTTP? You probably do, even if you automatically redirect to HTTPS from there - users might use old bookmarks, old links, etc. that still use the HTTP URLs, and if you disabled that version of the site, all those users would only land on an error page.

Comment: thank you but I was wondering if in one file.conf I put both configurations http and https or do I need both files.conf : 
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName 
    ServerAlias 
    Redirect permanent / https://site/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    ServerName 
    ServerAlias

Comment: Leave it as it is, that way you’ll do the least amount of damage ;-) You will still need at least the two separate VHosts entries anyway. If you are working in a setup that uses sites-available, sites-enabled etc. for configuration, you should not mess with the configuration files manually.